# How to calculate the range of $a$ that satisfies $a^x>x$ for any real number $x$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, inequalities

I'm trying to calculate the range of $a$ that satisfies $a^x>x$ for any real number $x$. `Reduce[a^x > x, a]` fails. If it's not possible to get a *symbolic* answer, a numerical solution is also okay.

An answer showed `Reduce[a^x > x, a, Reals]`, and it does help, but I need a constant range of $a$ not relative to $x$. For example, $2^x>x$ is true for any real $x$, but $1.1^x>x$ is false. How can I calculate the constant point from which the inequality holds true?

Comment: The obvious `Resolve[ForAll[x, a^x > x], Reals]` is unable to resolve this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe the result of `Reduce` as given by user64494:

```
Reduce[a^x > x, a, Reals]
```

> (x == 0 && a < 0) || (x <= 0 && a > 0) || (x > 0 && a > x^(1/x))

Note that the critical question is "what is the minimum possible value of $a$ such that $x^{1/x}$ is always less than $a$?" This minimum will occur at some variety of critical point of $a=x^{1/x}$.

Solve for `x`:

```
Solve[a == x^(1/x), x]
```

> {{ x -> -ProductLog[-Log[a]]/Log[a] }}

Plug in a few values and notice that for small values these x values are strictly real (meaning there is a crossing point in the reals where this equality is satisfied and as such $a > x^{1/x}$ is not satisfied), and large values they are complex (meaning the equation is never satisfied with a real $x$ value).

By intuition, I assumed that the critical point is `Exp[1/E]`. I will leave it to someone more familiar with the intricacies of `ProductLog` to explain why.

Observe `Plot[{Exp[1/E]^x, x}, {x, -5, 5}]` and note that it contacts at exactly one point. For larger $a$ values than `Exp[1/E]`, it will clearly always be greater than $x$, and for smaller values it will cross more than once.

> [image: plot of power of critical a versus x]

**Edit:**

Naturally, re-reading one's own answer can lead to dramatically simpler insights. I say earlier that "what is the minimum possible value of $a$ such that $x^{1/x}$ is always less than $a$". Naturally, this is the maximum of $x^{1/x}$:

```
Maximize[x^(1/x),x]
```

> E^(1/E)

Answer (score 2):

By default `a` and `x` are assumed complex. The `Reals` domain helps

```
Reduce[a^x > x, a, Reals]
```

> `(x == 0 && a < 0) || (x <= 0 && a > 0) || (x > 0 && a > x^(1/x))`

Comment: Thanks, but I need something slightly different. Please have a look at the edit.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment, the general

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, a^x > x], Reals]
```

Does not work. For specific values of $a$ we can define

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := Boole@Resolve[ForAll[x, a^x > x]]
```

and then plot

```
Plot[f[a], {a, 1, 2}, GridLines -> {{E^(1/E)}, {}}]
```

[image]

which gives an idea of the range of values of $a$ for which the statement is true, and confirms @eyorble's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275928/26598).